# Query SQL Server DB with PHP & ODBC from Linux box

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, odbc

This is not a connection issue. I was given a query statement (See Below) so I have an idea of the DB structure. But when I do a simple Query: I am getting an error. There are "/" in the Field names. Do I need to escape those?

Warning: odbc_exec() [function.odbc-exec]: SQL error: [unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'Host'., SQL state S0022 in SQLExecDirect in

Query in PHP

```
$query ="SELECT General/Host Title FROM TempReservations";
```

SQL Server Statement

```
CREATE TABLE  #TempReservations    (
    [Reservation_ID] [int] Null, 
    [General/Meeting Title] nVarchar(4000)  NULL ,
    [General/Host] nVarchar(200)  NULL ,
    [Room_ID] [int] NULL)
```

Comment: Use brackets for the fields - just like in the table definition snippet you posted.  So you could use `SELECT [General\Host Title] FROM #TempReservations`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in @Andrew's comment, you can use brackets to delimit your column name.  The links provide more information about [identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx) and [delimited identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176027.aspx).